# Regular Expression to match and split with operator in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need a regular expression that matches exact keywords as well as special characters or operators.

For instance, I have a string and I want to split this with regular expression.

```
 my $data="long i = sbyte.MinValue ; i => sbyte.MaxValue ; > i++";
```

If I split this on the equals character `=` then it should return two strings:

1. `long i`
2. `sbyte.MinValue ; i => sbyte.MaxValue ; > i++`

If I split with `=>` then it will return:

1. `long i = sbyte.MinValue ; i`
2. `sbyte.MaxValue ; > i++`

Here is the example code:

```
my $key = "=";

my $data = "long i = sbyte.MinValue ; i => sbyte.MaxValue ; > i++";

#=~/\b$s\b/
#/\b$key\b/

my @matches = ( $data =~/\b$key\b/ );

my @string = split (/\b$key\b/, $data); # split ~ /^=$/, $data;

if ( scalar(@string) > 0 ) {

    foreach my $item ( @string ) {
        print "$item \n";
    }
}
else {
    print "Nothing found \n";
}
```

The issue comes with an operator to search and split in string.
Exact match works with keywords or other text, but with operators
like `=`, `>=`, `<=`, `!=`, `<<=`, `=>>`, `++`, `--` it's not working.

I need to search one by one and split the text.

Comment: Should this have the C# tag?

Comment: yes any tag but the issue in regex is to not work with operatior.

Comment: What is the result you are looking for?

Comment: You don't appear to have asked a question, and it's far from clear what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a tokenizer to handle parsing the string for you, so as not to reinvent the wheel.  Here is an example using [PPI::Tokenizer](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/PPI-1.215/lib/PPI/Tokenizer.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw( any );
use PPI::Tokenizer;

my @operators_i_care_about = qw( = => >= <= != <<= =>> ++ -- );

my $data = "long i = sbyte.MinValue ; i => sbyte.MaxValue ; > i++";

my $tokenizer = PPI::Tokenizer->new( \$data );

for my $token ( @{ $tokenizer->all_tokens } ) {
    if ( 'PPI::Token::Operator' eq ref $token
         and any { $_ eq $token->content } @operators_i_care_about ) {
         print "\nOPERATOR: $token\n";
    } else {
        print $token; # Stringifies
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
long i
OPERATOR: =
 sbyte.MinValue ; i
OPERATOR: =>
 sbyte.MaxValue ; > i
OPERATOR: ++
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still very hazy about what you're trying to do, but the immediate problem I can see in your code is that you have a regex pattern of `\b=\b` while the equals sign `=` appears in your target string only preceded by a space and followed by a space or a greater-than sign `>`

The zero-width pattern `\b` matches the position between a word character and a non-word character or the beginning or end of the string

Word characters include only upper and lower-case letters, decimal digits, and the underscore `_`, so equals, space and greater-than are all non-word characters, and your regex pattern matches nowhere in the string

It's likely that you meant the equals sign to be surrounded by space characters, and you can do that with `\s=\s`, or if you want the beginning and end of the string to work in the same way as they do for `\b` then you can use negative look-arounds with `(?<!\S)=(?!\S)`